# How do I make the bot copy the url link of an image after it has been deleted in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So what I'm trying to do is make the bot get the link of the image the a user sent and make the bot snipe the image. It needs to be an event not a command, But when i made my own and clicked the link its says this[image]
[image]
Here's the code I made. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
        print(message.attachments)
```

Comment: Once the author or someone else deletes the message the message is removed from the database of `Discord` so there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `Attachment.proxy_url`, the url might be valid for a few minutes or not valid at all. Take that in note

Comment: When I used that and deleted an image. It just says this 
<member 'proxy_url' of 'Attachment' objects>